# When was the function 1 + cos(x), aka the vercosine, given a name?

Tags: mathematics, terminology

Nowadays, when one searches for little-known trigonometric functions, one usually finds a list containing the versine, coversine, vercosine, and covercosine. When using this list, $1+\cos(x)$ is given the name vercosine. However, I have not found any references to this before the year 2009, when it was added to Wikipedia.

In contrast, I can easily find references to the versine and coversine back to at least Cauchy's 1821 "Analyse Algébrique". Cauchy calls the coversine the *cosinus versus*, which formula is $1-\sin(x)$. A more detailed history can be found in [Miller's Earliest Known Uses](http://jeff560.tripod.com/v.html). I have seen this function also called the vercosine, for instance in [MathHorizon (2006)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/MathHorizons/JBYrAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=vercosine&dq=vercosine&printsec=frontcover) and the [Science Vocabulary builder by Johnson O'Connor in 1956](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Science_Vocabulary_Builder/mZTWAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=vercosine&dq=vercosine&printsec=frontcover).

Is there any source before 2009 where the function $1 + \cos(x)$ was given a name?

Comment: In which 2009 reference did you find the mention of $1+\cos(x)$ as vercosine? Also, $1-\sin(x)$ being called vercosine are a result of translation errors.

Comment: Versine much predates Cauchy, see [Miller's Earliest known uses](http://jeff560.tripod.com/v.html):"*In Practica geomitrae, Fibonacci used the term sinus versus arcus... Regiomontanus (1436-1476) used sinus versus for the versed sine in De triangulis omnimodis (On triangles of all kinds; Nuremberg, 1533)*". The concept is much older and goes back to *Surya Siddhanta* (c. 400 AD). Extending terms people are vague on the meaning of by association is quite common.

Comment: The 2009 reference is Wikipedia.

Comment: I am aware that _sinus versus_ and _cosinus versus_ have a long history, which is why I wasn't that concerned about giving the full history. But that's still helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The historical name of this function is the *suversed sine*, *suversine*, or *susinus versus*, and is abbreviated $\operatorname{suvers}(x)$. (Similarly, the function $1 + \sin(x)$ is called the *cosuversine* or *sucoversine*.) The earliest use of this name may be in 1801 by Joseph de Mendoza y Rios.

We see in [Gregory and Law's 1862 *Mathematics for Practical Men*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mathematics_for_Practical_Men/jqFfD3S-eJAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=suversine&pg=PA137&printsec=frontcover),

> 12. The *suversine* of an arc is the versed sine of its supplement, as $A'D$.

In [Snowball's 1837 *The elements of plane trigonometry*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_elements_of_plane_trigonometry/x1MEAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=suversine&pg=PA9&printsec=frontcover), we see

> 8. The versed sine of the supplement of the $\angle BAC$ is called the *suversine* of the $\angle BAC$;
>
> or, $\operatorname{suversin}\angle BAC = \operatorname{versin}(180^\circ -\angle BAC).$

Curiously, this source does not reference the coversine (or sucoversine) at all.

[Thomas Kerigan (1828)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Complete_Mathematical_and_General_Na/_ZtDAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=versed+sine+supplement&pg=PA58&printsec=frontcover) uses the term "versed sine supplement".

---

In [The Monthly Review, For October, 1806. Art. II](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Monthly_Review/Z-RKAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22suversed%22&pg=PA133&printsec=frontcover), it is suggested that Joseph de Mendoza y Rios is the originator of the name, from his *Tables for Navigation* (1806):

> We have mentioned certain terms, suversed, sucoversed, &c. which are novel in mathematical language; and M. Mendoza is, we believe, the author of the "*callida junctura*."— We subjoin the values of these lines, from which our readers may easily discern the reason for their denomination. Suppose the radius 1
> \begin{align}
> \text{then} \operatorname{versin.} A &= 1 - \operatorname{cos.} A \\
> \operatorname{suvers.} A &= 1 + \operatorname{cos.} A \\
> \operatorname{covers.} A &= 1 - \operatorname{sin.} A \\
> \operatorname{sucovers.} A &= 1 + \operatorname{sin.} A
> \end{align}

Actually, the suversed sine and sucoversed sine are mentioned in [Mendoza's earlier 1801 set of tables](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Tables_for_Facilitating_the_Calculations/FzIAAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=suversed).
However, no justification for the terms is given, which suggests that they were either already in common use or had sufficiently obvious names.